# react prop is undefined in child component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

**Main.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Books from './Books'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import AddBook from './AddBook';
import BookDetail from './BookDetail';

const Main = () => {
    let [selectedBook, setSelectedBook] = useState()  // Storing the data from Books.js
    let [books, setBooks] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-books')
            .then(res => {
                setBooks(books = res.data)
            })
    })

    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Navbar title={selectedBook}/> // is defined here <----
                <div className='container'>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' >
                            <Books books={books} onBookSelect={(book) => {setSelectedBook(book)} }/>  // Receiving the data from here
                        </Route>

                        <Route path='/add-book' >
                            <AddBook />
                        </Route>

                        <Route path={`/details`} >
                            <BookDetail bookId={selectedBook} /> // is undefined when passed here <----
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Main
```

**Books.js**

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react'
import BookDetail from './BookDetail'

const Books = ({books, onBookSelect}) => {

    const sendBookId = e => {
        let bookId = e.target.value 
        onBookSelect('i am not undefined') // sending the data to Main.js
        setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href='http://localhost:3000/details' }, 10)
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <div className='books'>
                {books.map(book => (
                    <div className='book'> 
                        <h2>{book.name}</h2>
                        <p>Author: <a href='#'>{book.author}</a></p>
                        <button className="btn" value={book.id} onClick={sendBookId}>View Details</button>  // Getting the id from here
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Books
```

**BookDetail.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useState } from 'react'

const BookDetail = ({bookId}) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <p>book: {bookId}</p>  // bookId is undefined
        </div>
    )
}

export default BookDetail
```

**Sample from localhost:8000/api/get-books**

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Book1",
    "author": "Author1",
    "content": "a normal book",
    "isbn": "235456",
    "passcode": "123",
    "created_at": "2021-07-12T16:29:47.114356Z",
    "pages": "3"
}
```

Basically, the data is sent from Book.js to the parent component which is Main.js and which is stored in selectedBook, and the data is defined and displays in the title, but when I add it as a prop in  and try to access it from there it becomes undefined, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with this code. Can you add a sample `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-books` response so that we can try to reproduce the issue, or can you try creating a ***running*** codesandbox with the mocked response that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: i added the sample!

Comment: In your code, there's no indication of how you actually navigate to `/details`?

Comment: yeah, i removed that part but i re-added it now (its located in Books.js in the sendBookId function)

Comment: I see it, and incidentally this is your problem. With the way you navigate, you're completely reloading the whole app. Meaning you'll lose any app state until this point. So selecting the book is also lost. Which brings up the point, why you don't use the route as a means to keep track of the selected book? For example `<Route path={'/details/:bookId'} >...</Route>`?

Comment: Copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-prop-is-undefined-in-child-component-tozmj?file=/src/App.js) and I see the state update as you're expecting.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I see the issue now with your update/edit for the way you are navigating. Use the `Link` component or use the `history` object from `react-router-dom` like I had to add to push to a new route. It was late last night, but I noticed today also that your `useEffect` hook in `Main` is missing the dependency array, so it's going to cause a lot of unnecessary data fetches, state updates, and rerenders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Credit to Yoshi for calling it out first, but there is an issue with the way you navigate from your home page to the book details page. Mutating the `window.location.href` object will actually reload the page, and your app. Since React state lives in memory it is lost upon page reloading.

## Solution

Use the `history` object provided by the `Router` context to PUSH to the new route. Since you are already using a function component you can import the `useHistory` React hook from `react-router-dom` and issue the imperative navigation.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const Books = ({ books, onBookSelect }) => {
  const history = useHistory(); // <-- access the history object from hook

  const sendBookId = (e) => {
    const bookId = e.target.value;
    onBookSelect(bookId);
    history.push("/details"); // <-- issue PUSH to route
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="books">
        Books
        {books.map((book) => (
          <div className="book">
            <h2>{book.name}</h2>
            <p>
              Author: <a href="#">{book.author}</a>
            </p>
            <button className="btn" value={book.id} onClick={sendBookId}>
              View Details
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-prop-is-undefined-in-child-component]

Comment: It does work because the title doesnt disappear but for some reason it still undefined in BookDetail... let me add it here

Comment: @Luna The book id? It's working in the sandbox. Can you clarify what is still undefined for you? Feel free to fork my sandbox and apply your code so we can see what may be different.

Comment: IT WORKS, i removed the backticks from {``/details``} to {"/details"} and for some reason its working now, thank you so much guys!